# How can I make a skill legendary?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim after v 1.9 patch you can make a skill legendary. How can I make a skill legendary? If I make enough skills legendary will I hit the level 252 cap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must first max out the skill (reach 100) then you will have the option to make the skill legendary on the skill tree screen. You can see more on this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EywdFsyU5sc).

Yes you can.

Answer (score -2):

on pc press space bar, on xbox press y, on playstation press triangle, of course the skill needs to hit 100 first, you can do this an unlimited amount of times, to all of the skill potentially removing level cap from the game

Comment: Hi Bob, this doesn't add much that wasn't already covered in the accepted answer as there are prompts on screen telling you what you need to press to make a skill legendary.

Answer (score -3):

To make a skill legendary, you max out the skill to level 100. If you are playing the Xbox 360 version, it will then prompt you to press y on the controller, and it'll give you 15 level points and set the skill's level back to 15.